# Can't display boxAndWhisker canvasJS

Tags: json, canvasjs

I would like to display  values  on boxAndWhisker graph with canvasJS.
I can display axis with X labels and Y values but i can't display boxAndWhisker graph

This is my code

```
 <c:out value="${pointdata}" escapeXml="false" />
<script type="text/javascript">

window.onload = function() { 

        
var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
    animationEnabled: true,
    theme: "light2",
    title:{
        text: "sondes 42"
    },
    subtitles: [{
        text: "controle"
    }],
    
    axisY: {
        title: "intensite des sondes",
        
    },
    data: [{
        type: "boxAndWhisker",
        
        yValueFormatString: "###.##",
        dataPoints :  <%out.print(dataPoints) ;%>
    }]
});
chart.render();
 
}
```

My pointdata values(json format) :

```
[{"y":[146.86,141.54,166.51,121.42],"label":"May 7, 2021 3:24:10 PM"},{"y":[146.86,141.54,166.51,121.42,142.23,135.64,121.04,130.38,132.5,134.26,140.98,121.07,131.79,145.17],"label":"May 6, 2021 3:05:23 PM"},{"y":[146.86,141.54,166.51,121.42,142.23,135.64,121.04,130.38,132.5,134.26,140.98,121.07,131.79,145.17,108.57,119.04,120.21,107.85,106.53,99.82,115.4,95.98],"label":"May 17, 2021 11:46:58 AM"}]
```

The display graph

[image: Display graph]

I don't know how to display boxAndWhisker

Comment: The y array should contain 5 values in box and whisker plot representing minimum, lower quartile, median / mean , upper quartile and maximum values.

Comment: Check out this [Box and Whisker](https://canvasjs.com/docs/charts/chart-types/html5-box-and-whisker-chart/) page for more information.

Comment: Thanks  ! it's working now